# ways for Direct2D and Direct3D Interoperability

Tags: c++, overlay, direct3d, direct2d, dxgi

I want make a Direct2D GUI that will run on a DLL and will render with the Direct3D of the application that I inject into it.

I know that I can simply use `ID2D1Factory::CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget` to make a DXGI surface and use it as d2d render target, but this require enabling the flag `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT` on Direct3D's device.

The problem is that the application creates its device without enabling this flag and, for this reason, `ID2D1Factory::CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget` fails.

I am trying to find a other way to draw on the application window (externally or inside window's render target) that also works if that window is in full-screen.

I tried these alternatives so far:

1. Create a d2d render target with `ID2D1Factory::CreateDCRenderTarget`. This worked, but the part I rendered was blinking/flashing (show and hide very fast in loop). I also called `ID2D1DCRenderTarget::BindDC` before `ID2D1RenderTarget::BeginDraw`, but it just blinks but a bit less, so I still had the same issue.
2. Create a new window that will always be on the top of every other window and render there with d2d but, if the application goes into full-screen, then this window does not show on screen.
3. Create a second D3D device with enabled the `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT` flag and share an `ID3D11Texture2D` resource between the device of the window and my own, but I wasn't able to make it work... There are not a lot of examples on how to do it. The idea was to create a 2nd device, draw with d2d on that device and then sync the 2 D3D devices – I followed [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/surface-sharing-between-windows-graphics-apis#sample-synchronized-surface-sharing-between-two-direct3d-101-devices) (with direct11).
4. Create a D2D device and share the data of d2d device with d3d device; but, when I call `ID2D1Factory1::CreateDevice` to create the device it fails because the D3D device is created without enabling the `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT` flag. I started with [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/devices-and-device-contexts).

I've heard of hardware overlay but it works only on some graphics cards and I think I will have problems with this https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/win32/medfound/hardware-overlay-support.

I am currently at a dead end; I don't know what to do. Does anyone have any idea that may help me?

Maybe is there any way to draw on screen and work even if a window is in full-screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The #3 is the correct one. Here’s a few tips.

Don’t use keyed mutexes. Don’t use NT handles. The only flag you need is `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED`.

To properly synchronize access to the shared texture across devices, use queries. Specifically, you need a query of type `D3D11_QUERY_EVENT`. The workflow should look like following.

1. Create a shared texture on one device, open in another one. Doesn’t matter where it’s created and where imported. Don’t forget the `D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET` flag. Also create a query.
2. Create D2D device with CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget of the shared texture, render your overlay into the shared texture with D2D and/or DirectWrite.
3. On the immediate D3D device context with the BGRA flag which you use for D2D rendering, call `ID3D11DeviceContext.End` once, passing the query. Then wait for the `ID3D11DeviceContext.GetData` to return S_OK. If you care about electricity/thermals use `Sleep(1)`, or if you prioritize latency, busy wait with `_mm_pause()` instructions.
4. Once `ID3D11DeviceContext.GetData` returned S_OK for that query, the GPU has finished rendering your 2D scene. You can now use that texture on another device to compose into 3D scene.

The way to compose your 2D content into the render target depends on how do you want to draw your 2D content.

If that’s a small opaque quad, you can probably `CopySubresourceRegion` into the render target texture.

Or, if your 2D content has transparent background, you need a vertex+pixel shaders to render a quad (4 vertices) textured with your shared texture. BTW you don’t necessarily need a vertex/index buffer for that, there’s a [well-known trick](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/609917-full-screen-quad-without-vertex-buffer/) to do without one. Don’t forget about blend state (you probably want alpha blending), depth/stencil state (you probably want to disable depth test when rendering that quad), also the `D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE` flag for the shared texture.

P.S. There’s another way. Make sure your code runs in that process before the process created their Direct3D device. Then use something like [minhook](https://github.com/TsudaKageyu/minhook) to intercept the call to D3D11.dll::D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain, in the intercepted function set that BGRA bit you need then call the original function. Slightly less reliable because there’re multiple ways to create a D3D device, but easier to implement, will work faster, and use less memory.

Comment: i try to avoid hooks because i afraid of the anticheat detections, i had the idea to use minhook to hook that function (or change that argument value in the complied application) but both are easy to get detected. The 1st way with shared texture need any hook (eg: render it where the application render the main graphics)?

Comment: @modZz The first method only using supported APIs, no hooks. See the update, hope the workflow is better now.

Comment: I wouldn’t worry too much about the detection. Hooking a Windows-implemented API function like `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` is not trivially easy to detect because Microsoft is replacing the implementation with windows updates. In modern Windows, Microsoft can even move the implementation across DLLs without breaking binary compatibility of the programs consuming the API.

Comment: thanks for your answer i' ll try create that with shared texture because some times i want inject and un-inject the dll while application running. The hook requires load always the DLL at application startup

Comment: after the step 4 (ID3D11DeviceContext.GetData returned S_OK) what i should do to draw that texture? I made the code until there and it compiles and running without errors, but it not draw the d2d graphics

Comment: @modZz See the update

Comment: check my update. I try to make it with CopySubresourceRegion as it looks easier and later i can try the other way with buffers. So my code as i wrote it not give any error but i dont see the d2d texture. I'm new in D3D

Comment: how can i open the shared 2Dtexture on the other device? You told me not use handles, but the only way i can find is this function thats use handle ID3D11Device::OpenSharedResource

Comment: @modZz I recommended not to use **NT** handles, which is `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE` flag. Microsoft recommends the opposite but I remember compatibility issues with NT handles.

Comment: so i opened that texture in the other device and after that the function `CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget` fails

Comment: @modZz Find out why it fails. For one, you have HRESULT codes, you should pass them into FormatMessage API. Another thing, Windows SDK comes with D3D validation layer, can be enabled when creating a device. Same applies to D2D. Enable both debug layers, run with debugger attached, and there's very high chance the debug output will print what was wrong.

Comment: HRESULT message: "The parameter is incorrect." and the DEBUG message: "D2D DEBUG WARNING - The Direct3D device was not created with D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT, and therefore is not compatible with Direct2D."

Comment: @modZz See, the debug message tells you precisely what’s wrong. Maybe you’re trying to share a BGRA texture. If that’s the case, change the pixel format to RGBA. Or maybe you’re using the wrong D3D device or texture. If you have created your shared texture on the main device and imported into your own BGRA one, you must use the imported texture object to initialize D2D, or flip sharing direction (i.e. create the texture on BGRA device and import into the main one).

Comment: i did a lot changes not and i found and fixed a lot mistakes i had. Can you see the question again?

Comment: @modZz The first error is easy to fix, remove the Begin() call. See the documentation for `D3D11_QUERY_EVENT` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ne-d3d11-d3d11_query note it says “Begin is disabled”

Comment: @modZz The second one is harder to solve. CopySubresourceRegion doesn’t support partial copies of MSAA textures. To show your overlay in the MSAA render target, you need to render a textured quad. This means you need to create at least vertex+pixel shaders, depth+stencil state, and maybe blend state, on your main D3D device to compose your overlay into the main 3D scene.

Comment: @modZz As a quick workaround to test things, disable MSAA in the game settings. Proper workaround is rendering the textured quad, still.

Comment: i assume the game already has vertex+pixel shaders, depth+stencil state, and blend state. Do you mean i should create a 2nd pipeline? This will not cause compatibility problems?

Comment: i make a simple D3D11 application for faster testing and i try this code there at the moment. I solved the issue with CopySubresourceRegion, it only needed to make the last argument NULL and create the texture with same dimensions as the backbuffer

Comment: @modZz The game surely has tons of shaders and render states. However, these things were created by the game developers to render game’s visuals. For your use case, you need to render your own visual the game’s unaware of. You don’t need second pipeline, you need to inject your draw calls immediately before the game calls Present(). Ideally, save and then restore the pieces of state you modify, i.e. call `OMGetBlendState`, `OMGetDepthStencilState`, etc., before binding your things, draw your textured quad, then restore these pieces of state to the values set by the game.

Comment: Could you write a workflow on how to do that with vertex+pixel buffers, depth+stencil state, blend state and render it? I'm new on Direct3D and i'm a bit confused. I tried but i'm not sure what to do exactly.