# Anyone else notcing delays of shared d3dtexture2D betweeen two processes?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, game-engine, direct3d

I have two processes: Unity.exe and MyPathTracer.exe. And I share a ID3D11Texture2D between them(MyPathTracer.exe writes it, and Unity.exe reads it), same things as the image below (copied from https://github.com/keijiro/KlakSpout).

I keep the camera parameters of the two processes synchronized in real-time, and then blend the rendering results in Unity.exe

However, there is a significant delays when Unity.exe blends its rendering result with the shared texture written by MyPathTracer.exe

Does it already have a fixed delay implemented in the dirver? Or is it the delay caused by my IPC (pass camera params)?

BTW, I refer [ways for Direct2D and Direct3D Interoperability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69589509/ways-for-direct2d-and-direct3d-interoperability) for sharing texture code.

[image: share texture between two processes]